# Android Images not appear in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter

I made an application extending an activity, all worked fine.
To improve the application I changed the activity to Fragment (using onCreateView , onActivityCreated), but now all the images not shown.
I don't get any errors.

I open the Fragments inside the FragmentActivity using FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

Is there something I'm missing ?

Fragment XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minWidth="170dp"
        android:maxWidth="170dp"
        android:minHeight="170dp"
        android:maxHeight="170dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_pic"
        android:id="@+id/iv_profile_img"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeview_search_bar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_image"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment Class:

```
public class TempActivity extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "SearchCars";

    ArrayList<ListUser> userChatItems;
    MessagesAdapter mAdapter;

    FragmentActivity con;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_listview_users_profiles, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //con = this.getContext();
        con = this.getActivity();

        Log.v(TAG, "Initializing ...");

        View v = getView();
    }
}
```

PageAdapter:

```
public class PageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    public PageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new MyProfileActivity();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Main Fragment Activity:

```
public class MainFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_fragment);

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PageAdapter pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: we need some code snippet to guess what you are missing

Comment: whats the use of android:layout_below="@+id/relativeview_search_bar"?

Comment: there was a search bar before, I remove that now but nothing changed. I see the border of the image but not the image

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well I found that if I change to **android:src** instead of **app:srcCompat**
all is working fine.

It's probably better to use app:secCompat when extending from AppCompatActivity
But, when I use Fragment it doesn't work any more.

Comment: I had the opposite situation and had to change `app:srcCompat` to `android:src` because my fragment extends Fragment from **support-fragments** and not from **appcompat** package.