# ImageView In Fragment not showing

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-imageview

I have a strange issue that I have a workaround for but wondered if anyone could shed some light on why this is happening and a more elegant fix maybe?

I have a ViewPager with a series of Fragments. The Fragments use their own layout and when an ImageView is added to the layout the ImageView isnt rendered at runtime.

If I explicitly set the imageDrawable for the ImageView inside the Fragment's onCreateView method (even though the image is the same image as being referenced in the layout xml then the image shows fine.

Here is my Fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/baseRelLayout"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/flamerite_remote_6"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:id="@+id/remote6ButtonImage"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/remote9ButtonImage" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is where I am re-setting the image drawable inside onCreateView

```
public class WizardFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String STEP_NUMBER = "STEP_NUMBER";

    public static  final WizardFragment newInstance(String message){
        WizardFragment f = new WizardFragment();
        Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
        bdl.putString(STEP_NUMBER,message);

        f.setArguments(bdl);
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.wizard_fragment_step_1, container, false);
        ImageView remoteImage9Button = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.remote9ButtonImage);
        remoteImage9Button.setImageDrawable(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.flamerite_remote_9, null)); //THIS IS THE LINE THAT MAKES THE IMAGE WORK AGAIN
        return v;
    }
}
```

I can of course keep this re-set of the imageDrawable in but think it is strange that the image shoudlnt be showing when only set in the xml layout

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!!

Comment: you've put remote9ButtonImage in your code but it's remote6ButtonImage in your xml for the ids

Comment: Sorry, this code is simplified there were actually 2 images, remote6 and remote9, ive deleted one of them here for clarity but obvisouly not a matching pair! Doh! But in the full code I am setting the image for both (remote6 and remote9)

Comment: Is that a vector image though?

Comment: No, its just a png

Comment: Try changin it for `android:src="@drawable/flamerite_remote_6"` then. It should work as it is, but maybe it's some weird bug

Comment: Thanks Roman, I did try that but unfortunately it made no difference.
Nevermind, il just keep the drawable declarations in the code

Comment: I found the answer from link below. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40320173/android-images-not-appear-in-fragment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I do not know the reason, but in my case the same issue was resolved when I changed

image src definition from

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/logo"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `android:src="@drawable/logo"` instead of `app:srcCompat`

Comment: Yes, this did work for me.  Either this or "setImageResource" hardcode. Cheers.